# Popular Items in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I have two tables which I want to use in order to determine the "popularity" of a stream_post. Stream_Post_Comment and Stream_Post_Like.

```
stream_post_comment_id  stream_post_id  user_id
1                             1            1        
2                             2            1        
3                             2            4        
4                             2            1    



stream_post_like_id stream_post_id  user_id
1                           1           1   
2                           2           3   
3                           3           2   
4                           3           1
```

I am having trouble conceptualizing a query which would output something like this:

```
stream_post_id popularity
      1            1
      2            3 
      3            2
```

Where a user_id is only counted once in the popularity score of a given post.  If they commented and liked a post for instance, they would only count as "1" popularity score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  stream_post_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS popularity
FROM
(
   SELECT stream_post_id, user_id
   FROM stream_post_comment
   UNION ALL
   SELECT stream_post_id, user_id
   FROM stream_post_like
) AS sub
GROUP BY stream_post_id;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5b2c/1)

This will give you:

```
| STREAM_POST_ID | POPULARITY |
-------------------------------
|              1 |          1 |
|              2 |          3 |
|              3 |          2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems this should be something that's stored, and updated whenever a comment or like is triggered.

You could write a PHP script to calculate and populate the "popularity" field initially, then after that, use a trigger that updates the count each time something new happens - which would have a check within it that makes sure it doesn't increment it if the user already had a like or comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
      stream_post_id, 
      count(user_id) AS 'popularity'
FROM 
       (SELECT 
              stream_post_id, 
              user_id 
       FROM 
              Stream_Post_Comment 
       UNION
       SELECT 
              stream_post_id, 
              user_id 
       FROM 
              Stream_Post_Like) tbl
GROUP BY 
       stream_post_id
```

Hope this helps